android release .aab crashes, but .apk works fine
android release .aab crashes, but .apk works fine (and metro debug)
i added any one of these packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/freerasp-react-native

I have some relevent files below.
I cannot figure out why aab is crashing.
If i do not add those libraries, aab file works fine.
logcat output
08-14 17:41:52.418  1467  4771 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity bnds=[856,525][1024,795]} with LAUNCH_SINGLE_TASK from uid 10210 (BAL_ALLOW_ALLOWLISTED_COMPONENT) result code=0
08-14 17:41:52.419  2052  2069 V WindowManagerShell: Transition requested (#33): android.os.BinderProxy@6ba7c0e TransitionRequestInfo { type = OPEN, triggerTask = TaskInfo{userId=0 taskId=5103 displayId=0 isRunning=true baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity } baseActivity=ComponentInfo{com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity} topActivity=ComponentInfo{com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity} origActivity=null realActivity=ComponentInfo{com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity} numActivities=1 lastActiveTime=2529578 supportsMultiWindow=true resizeMode=1 isResizeable=true minWidth=-1 minHeight=-1 defaultMinSize=220 token=WCT{android.window.IWindowContainerToken$Stub$Proxy@7462f} topActivityType=1 pictureInPictureParams=null shouldDockBigOverlays=false launchIntoPipHostTaskId=-1 lastParentTaskIdBeforePip=-1 displayCutoutSafeInsets=Rect(0, 118 - 0, 0) topActivityInfo=ActivityInfo{1d5643c com.mobile.MainActivity} launchCookies=[android.os.BinderProxy@ece25c5] positionInParent=Point(0, 0) parentTaskId=-1 isFocused=false isVisible=false isVisibleRequested=false isSleeping=false locusId=null displayAreaFeatureId=1 isTopActivityTransparent=false appCompatTaskInfo=AppCompatTaskInfo { topActivityInSizeCompat=false topActivityEligibleForLetterboxEducation= false isLetterboxDoubleTapEnabled= false topActivityEligibleForUserAspectRatioButton= false topActivityBoundsLetterboxed= false isFromLetterboxDoubleTap= false topActivityLetterboxVerticalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxHorizontalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxWidth=1080 topActivityLetterboxHeight=2400 isUserFullscreenOverrideEnabled=false isSystemFullscreenOverrideEnabled=false cameraCompatControlState=hidden}}, pipTask = null, remoteTransition = RemoteTransition { remoteTransition = android.window.IRemoteTransition$Stub$Proxy@8a64b1a, appThread = android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy@9cc164b, debugName = QuickstepLaunch }, displayChange = null, flags = 0, debugId = 33 }
08-14 17:41:52.433  1467  4771 D CoreBackPreview: Window{397c4d3 u0 Splash Screen com.myapp1.main}: Setting back callback OnBackInvokedCallbackInfo{mCallback=android.window.IOnBackInvokedCallback$Stub$Proxy@e4450e, mPriority=0, mIsAnimationCallback=false}
08-14 17:41:52.436  1467  1701 I ActivityManager: Start proc 21771:com.myapp1.main/u0a280 for next-top-activity {com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity}
08-14 17:41:52.447 21771 21771 I com.myapp1.main: Using CollectorTypeCMC GC.
08-14 17:41:52.450 21771 21771 E com.myapp1.main: Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.
08-14 17:41:52.450  1467  1668 V WindowManager: Sent Transition (#33) createdAt=08-14 17:41:52.408 via request=TransitionRequestInfo { type = OPEN, triggerTask = TaskInfo{userId=0 taskId=5103 displayId=0 isRunning=true baseIntent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity } baseActivity=ComponentInfo{com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity} topActivity=ComponentInfo{com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity} origActivity=null realActivity=ComponentInfo{com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity} numActivities=1 lastActiveTime=2529578 supportsMultiWindow=true resizeMode=1 isResizeable=true minWidth=-1 minHeight=-1 defaultMinSize=220 token=WCT{RemoteToken{b6c4641 Task{540055b #5103 type=standard A=10280:com.myapp1.main}}} topActivityType=1 pictureInPictureParams=null shouldDockBigOverlays=false launchIntoPipHostTaskId=-1 lastParentTaskIdBeforePip=-1 displayCutoutSafeInsets=Rect(0, 118 - 0, 0) topActivityInfo=ActivityInfo{c674c6a com.mobile.MainActivity} launchCookies=[android.os.BinderProxy@1c7e7e6] positionInParent=Point(0, 0) parentTaskId=-1 isFocused=false isVisible=false isVisibleRequested=false isSleeping=false locusId=null displayAreaFeatureId=1 isTopActivityTransparent=false appCompatTaskInfo=AppCompatTaskInfo { topActivityInSizeCompat=false topActivityEligibleForLetterboxEducation= false isLetterboxDoubleTapEnabled= false topActivityEligibleForUserAspectRatioButton= false topActivityBoundsLetterboxed= false isFromLetterboxDoubleTap= false topActivityLetterboxVerticalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxHorizontalPosition= -1 topActivityLetterboxWidth=1080 topActivityLetterboxHeight=2400 isUserFullscreenOverrideEnabled=false isSystemFullscreenOverrideEnabled=false cameraCompatControlState=hidden}}, pipTask = null, remoteTransition = RemoteTransition { remoteTransition = android.window.IRemoteTransition$Stub$Proxy@caa0127, appThread = android.app.IApplicationThread$Stub$Proxy@be68fd4, debugName = QuickstepLaunch }, displayChange = null, flags = 0, debugId = 33 }
08-14 17:41:52.450  1467  1668 V WindowManager:         {WCT{RemoteToken{b6c4641 Task{540055b #5103 type=standard A=10280:com.myapp1.main}}} m=OPEN f=NONE leash=Surface(name=Task=5103)/@0xf48fb4b sb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) eb=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2400) d=0},
08-14 17:41:52.465 21771 21771 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.dm': No such file or directory
08-14 17:41:52.465 21771 21771 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.dm': No such file or directory
08-14 17:41:52.465 21771 21771 W com.myapp1.main: Entry not found
08-14 17:41:52.465 21771 21771 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.en.dm': No such file or directory
08-14 17:41:52.465 21771 21771 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.en.dm': No such file or directory
08-14 17:41:52.466 21771 21771 W com.myapp1.main: Entry not found
08-14 17:41:52.466 21771 21771 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.xxhdpi.dm': No such file or directory
08-14 17:41:52.466 21771 21771 W ziparchive: Unable to open '/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.xxhdpi.dm': No such file or directory
08-14 17:41:52.466 21771 21771 W com.myapp1.main: Entry not found
08-14 17:41:52.467 21771 21771 D nativeloader: Configuring clns-4 for other apk /data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/base.apk:/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk:/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.en.apk:/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/lib/arm64:/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.en.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a:/data/app/~~2R-3lyBn8vw2eVC1klWK5w==/com.myapp1.main-Gd57b2s01g6crHw9iMuUeA==/split_config.xxhdpi.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, permitted_pa
08-14 17:41:52.472 21771 21771 V GraphicsEnvironment: com.myapp1.main is not listed in per-application setting
08-14 17:41:52.490 21771 21771 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.myapp1.main, PID: 21771
08-14 17:41:52.507  1467  2217 I ActivityManager: Process com.myapp1.main (pid 21771) has died: fg  TOP
08-14 17:41:52.706  2497  2497 D HotseatPredictionController: Predicted items: [WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.myapp1.main/com.mobile.MainActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Finmate AI), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.android.vending/com.android.vending.AssetBrowserActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Play Store), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.reddit.frontpage/launcher.default} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Reddit), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.youtube/com.google.android.youtube.app.honeycomb.Shell$HomeActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=YouTube), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.instagram.android/com.instagram.android.activity.MainTabActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Instagram), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.facebook.orca/com.facebook.orca.auth.StartScreenActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Messenger), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.snapchat.android/com.snapchat.android.LandingPageActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Snapchat), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{yducky.application.babytime/yducky.application.babytime.BabyTime} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=BabyTime), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.Slack/slack.features.home.HomeActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Slack), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.keep/com.google.android.keep.activities.BrowseActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Keep Notes), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping/com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Amazon Shopping), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.AllInOneActivity} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Calendar), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.deskclock/com.android.deskclock.DeskClock} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1,1) rank=0 user=UserHandle{0} title=Clock), WorkspaceItemInfo(id=-1 type=APP container=# com.android.launcher3.logger.LauncherAtom$ContainerInfo@19f79dd targetComponent=ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gm/com.google.android.gm.ConversationListActivityGmail} screen=-1 cell(-1,-1) span(1,1) minSpan(1
08-14 17:42:07.466  1467  1700 I ActivityManager: Skip zero pid ANR, process=com.myapp1.main
08-14 17:42:38.608 11172 11172 E ActivityThread: Package [com.myapp1.main] reported as REPLACED, but missing application info. Assuming REMOVED.

android build Gradle
...
buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            matchingFallbacks = ['debug', 'release']
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled false      // <--- show this minified is false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }


To resolve this, you could try the following steps:

Clear the app's data and cache(If app is already installed).

Uninstall and reinstall the app completely.

Check your app's manifest file for any issues.

Ensure that the package name in your build.gradle file matches the one in the manifest.


